# Wordpress conditional {is_future} breaks other conditionals within

Tags: html, wordpress, shortcode

I have the following code:

```
{is_future}
<tr>
    <td>#_EVENTLINK</td>
    <td>#d/#m/#Y</td>
    <td>#_EVENTNOOFDAYS</td>
    <td>#_EVENTTIMES</td>
    <td>{not_free}#_EVENTPRICEMAX{/not_free} {fully_booked}Geen plaatsen beschikbaar{/fully_booked}</td>
</tr>
{/is_future}
```

The problem is that it breaks the {not_free} tag (removing that causes it to break {fully_booked} instead), causing it to read as "{not_free}$3.50" instead of the actual price.
It seems to me that I'm not allowed to put conditional tags within other conditional tags.

Does anyone know a solution for this?
Thanks in advance.

**Edit: I am using the Wordpress Eventmanager plugin.**

Comment: Have you done what is described in the [Events Manager  documentation for Conditional Placeholders](http://wp-events-plugin.com/documentation/conditional-placeholders/) on the bottom, section _“Nesting Conditional Placeholders”_ …?

Comment: @CBroe Nevermind, it worked! I put the line higher and it's working now! Thanks a lot :)

Comment: OK, I’ll add it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Events Manager documentation for Conditional Placeholders](http://wp-events-plugin.com/documentation/conditional-placeholders/), section “Nesting Conditional Placeholders” on the very bottom:

> It is possible to use conditional placeholders within each other. However, by default Events Manager will only go one level deep, meaning it won’t check conditional placeholders within conditional placeholders. This is due to the extra processing required to acheive such behaviour.
>
> In order to enable further levels of nesting, you need to add a line of PHP to your wp-config.php file:
>
> `define('EM_CONDITIONAL_RECURSIONS',2);`
>
> The example above will go 2 levels down, meaning you could nest conditional placeholders within another conditional placeholder. If you wanted to nest one inside the nested placeholder, then you need to increase that number to 3.

Comment: Nice, this solved another issue for me aswell. They should note in the documentation that it's important to check where you're placing the line :P.

Comment: I'm having another issue where the price shows up as `€0,00 Geen plaatsen beschikbaar` when the event has been fully booked. It should be just the text, minus the 0.00 price. Would you happen to know what might be causing this?

Comment: You are showing the price on the condition `not_free`, and that has nothing to do with whether `fully_booked` is true or not. If you want the price not to show when the event is fully booked, then you will have to nest the price display into an additional `has_spaces` condition (opposite of `fully_booked`) … and don’t forget to increase your recursion level then ;-)

Comment: Man I wish I could double-accept your answer. It works!

Comment: If you want you can answer this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22507046/wordpress-conditional-shows-0-00-text-instead-of-just-text Where I made a seperate question for it. I didn't get an answer on it for a while so I though I'd ask you again :P.