# Wordpress conditional shows "$0.00 text" instead of "just text"

Tags: html, wordpress, conditional-statements, currency

I have the following code to show a table of coming events in my page:

```
{is_future}
<tr>
    <td>#_EVENTLINK</td>
    <td>#d/#m/#Y</td>
    <td>#_EVENTNOOFDAYS</td>
    <td>#_EVENTTIMES</td>
    <td>{not_free}#_EVENTPRICEMAX{/not_free} {fully_booked}Geen plaatsen beschikbaar{/fully_booked}</td>
</tr>
{/is_future}
```

This works fine for events that can still accept reservations.
However when an event has been booked full, it shows "€0,00 Geen plaatsen beschikbaar" instead of "Geen plaatsen beschikbaar".

It looks like it just sets the price to a default value when the event is fully booked.
Does anyone know what might be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are showing the price on the condition `not_free`, and that has nothing to do with whether `fully_booked` is true or not.

If you want the price not to show when the event is fully booked, then you will have to nest the price display into an additional `has_spaces` condition (opposite of `fully_booked`).

Reference: http://wp-events-plugin.com/documentation/conditional-placeholders/